# Can't write to log file in Passenger 2.2.5 with nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I have a Rails app, running with nginx and Passenger. Until yesterday, logging worked, but now nginx's error.log shows this message on startup:
    Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /var/www/app/htdocs/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

The log file *has* 0666 permissions. It looked like it may have been related to [Issue 332](http://github.com/FooBarWidget/passenger/commit/72416a55bff4c0dfe0aa7513e6963b3f9b4cdd7f), so I upgraded from Passenger 2.2.4 to 2.2.5. This didn't solve the issue. Logging worked yesterday, and nothing was changed in the configuration since then.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the directory privs as well:

```
ls -larth /var/www/app/htdocs/
```